# Whats wrong with my Oracle TRIGGER?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I have a sequence created  such as this:

```
CREATE Sequence index START WITH 1000;
```

My trigger code looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER user BEFORE INSERT ON CUSTOMERS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT index.nextval INTO :new.custid FROM DUAL;
END User;
```

I keep getting a "Trigger created with compilation errors" message but the rest of my code works. Anything I am overlooking? The error says "encountered the symbol "INSERT" "

Answer (score 3):

I suspect Oracle might be squawking because **`USER`** is a reserved word in Oracle. So is **`INDEX`**.

So, before anything else, I recommend attempting a test using identifiers that are not reserved words, and verify that you have a table in the same/current schema named `CUSTOMERS`, and that it contains a column named `CUSTID`.

(It's also remotely possible it's an issue with privileges, though if you didn't have CREATE TRIGGER privilege, then Oracle wouldn't be reporting "Trigger created...".

If we do find it necessary to use reserved words as object identifiers, we can enclose the identifiers in double quotes, but this also makes the identifier case-sensitive.